# What does "commercial interest" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

> Please describe your company's long-term commercial interest in the
> project country.

According to Cambridge Dictionary "interest" have several meanings:

...

2. (advantage) something that brings advantages to or affects someone or something
3. (money) money that is charged by a bank or other financial organization for borrowing money

...

Which one is true for the sentence above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Neither.

"Commercial interest" refers to the ownership of businesses within that country. It doesn't refer to a specific advantage, but in the ownership of a stake in something; you've put money down, you've got skin in the game, and you're actively working in that area to make money. For instance, if your business owns a portion of a Chinese fishing fleet, you would have a commercial interest in that region's fishing. If you're planning on starting a business mining diamonds in Africa, then once it started, you'd have a commercial interest in African diamond mining.

Comment: I would normally define commercial interest; An involvement or legal right relating to a business which is intended to make money:  However the question precludes that. I have now clarified that. P.S. "Chinese fishing fleet" is not really relevant, they operate in international waters. Africa is a continent and as such has numerous jurisdictions, not really a great example.

Answer (score -1):

Both your answer are little off the mark;

---

commercial; adjective; intended to make money, or relating to a business intended to make money:

interest; noun; (ADVANTAGE)

---

commercial interest definition; ***An advantage (real or speculative) relating to a business which is intended to make money:***

---

If the question was "Please describe your company's long-term commercial interests" I would have answered rather differently.

commercial interest definition;*** involvement or a legal right relating to a business which is intended to make money:***

Above Ref Cambridge Dictionary.